# how to iterate a ArrayList from session into JSP using Struts 2 OGNL tags

Tags: java, struts2

I have a class where I am creating a non empty `ArrayList` and putting it is not a session. Now, I want to iterate that list which kept in session into my JSP page.

I tried it but nothing is coming.

in action class

```
..................
books = new ArrayList<Bookdetails>();
session.put(BillTransactionBooksConstants.BOK, books);
return SUCCUSS;
```

Note : I tested my list is not empty and it is correctly adding into session.
My only problem is how can I show this list into my JSP from session.

`BillTransactionBooksConstants`:

```
package v.esoft.actions.booktransaction; 
public class BillTransactionBooksConstants 
{
    public static final String BOK = "BOK"; 
}
```

`shortbill.jsp`:

```
<s:iterator value="#session.BillTransactionBooksConstants.BOK" status="userStatus">
    <s:property value="Bookdetails.bookTitile" />
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: If would be better if the example showed that you put something into the books list.

Comment: @DaveNewton This is my Brother account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer only to the property name, and use the constant value directly:

```
<s:iterator value="#session.BOK">
    <s:property value="bookTitle" />
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Note that I've corrected the spelling of the property.

Also note that "SUCCESS" is spelled "SUCCESS", not "SUCCUSS".

If you wish to use the constant name you should be able to use the following, but I didn't test it:

```
<s:iterator value="#session[@v.esoft.actions.booktransaction.BillTransactionBooksConstants@BOK]">
```

Assuming static member access is enabled.

Comment: Isn't it static method access that needs to be enabled. Although... it is a static member and not a method.

Comment: bookTitile is not showing in the jsp .. only according to the list size number of rows are displaying without bookTitile. why?

Comment: @user1726508 Don't know, are you spelling the property name right?

Comment: yes coming fine. it was not visibile because the text color in css was white. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<s:iterator value="#session.BOK" status="userStatus">
<tr class="<s:if test="%{#userStatus.odd == true} ">odd</s:if> <s:else>even</s:else>">
<td><s:property value="bookTitile" /></td>
```

Comment: note to op: #session.BOK and #session['BOK'] should both work